# Copy an instance of class extended by Array

Tags: javascript

Let assume we got following class:

```js
class Content extends Array {
  delete (index) {
    return [...this.slice(0, index), ...this.slice(index + 1)]
  }

  copy () {
    // Create a copy!
  }
}

const content = new Content('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
const copy = content.copy()
console.log(copy.delete(1)) // ["alpha", "gamma"]
```

How can we create a copy of an instance of this class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not quite sure why you posted that.  It's a fairly simple question.  Maybe look for a duplicate?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Because the question doesn't show any attempt to solve the problem it presents, which (as I understand it) is expected, even nowadays. (I'm not trying to make new rules; I'm trying to follow the rules that the site has.) Copying an array subclass is *slightly* different from copying an array (although because Array's methods are fairly smart, most of the ways you do it just...work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.slice` can shallow-copy an array. Luckily, the new *instance* that `.slice` creates will be an instance of the subclass automatically; there's no need to do anything else manually, it'll automatically return a `Content` instance:

```js
class Content extends Array {
  delete (index) {
    return [...this.slice(0, index), ...this.slice(index + 1)]
  }

  copy () {
    return this.slice();
  }
}

const content = new Content('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
const copy = content.copy()
console.log(copy.delete(1)) // ["alpha", "gamma"]
```

As the [specification says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.slice), the new array-like object created, A, is created by:

> 8. Let A be ? ArraySpeciesCreate(O, count).

where `O` is the original array-like object being sliced. That's why `someArraySubclass.slice()` will return an object which is an instance of `SomeArraySubclass`.

Comment: Thank you! It's very handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `...this` inside your class to access the values inside the array.

The spread operators allows your to set the constructor parameters.

```js
class Content extends Array {
  delete (index) {
    return [...this.slice(0, index), ...this.slice(index + 1)]
  }

  copy () {
    return new Content(...this);
  }
}

const content = new Content('alpha', 'beta', 'gamma')
const copy = content.copy()
console.log(copy.delete(1)) // ["alpha", "gamma"]
```

EDIT: Please see comment below for potential issues with this solution

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Array constructor has some problems. `new Array(3)` will give an array with 3 empty slots, and no array-index own-properties, so `new Content(...this)` where the `...this` resolves to an array index won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comment. I had already upvoted your answer. Will leave my answer here with the EDIT so people can have a look

Comment: The usual solution is to use `Array.of` instead somehow. Maybe `Array.of.apply(Content, this)`, not sure if that would work. Or `Object.assign(Object.create(Content.prototype), this)`